# Need API for news

Tags: c#, asp.net, open-source, content-management-system, blogs

Anyone know of news API's I can use to retrieve news stories for use in an asp.net app?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You won't find whole solution made for you but you can certainly find APIs that will provide you with news.

I think [FeedZilla](http://code.google.com/p/feedzilla-api/) will do what you want. You can call its [API](http://code.google.com/p/feedzilla-api/wiki/RestApi) to get news and Embed in your app.

Also look at [Google news](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/news?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

That's kind of a vague question. After all, very few websites are not able to share news.

So how about http://www.dotnetblogengine.net?